# How to pass all rows on a table depending on a condition in ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am using SSIS 2019.

I have a scenario where I want to pass all rows in a table depending on a condition.

For Example

Source

[image: Source]

Source Has 4 rows.. one of the columns is a flag that has A and B values

if the flag = A
I want to pass the whole 4 rows from source to a table (not only the rows that has flag A)

if the flag = B
I want to pass the whole 4 rows from source to another table

[image]

its like a multicast transformation but with a condition ..

i tried to use conditional split using the condition

FLAG == 'A' ?  TRUE  :  FALSE

but this only passes the rows that has flag A ..

is there anyway to do this in ssis ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is Flag A *actually* being stored? You appear to reference it as both a column an a scalar value and it's impossible to tell when you're referencing which instance of it..

Comment: The source has the flag, i've edited the thread to simplify.

Comment: How can a flag for a row be a flag for a data set? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Also you say "if flag has A, all the rows go here, but if it has B all the rows go here". Your data has *both* flags; so should all the rows go to both destinations? You are still describing the flag like it's a scalar value, *not* a column within a data set

Comment: The idea is to move data from source to target 1 if the condition A is met and ignore target 2 .. OR move data from source to target 2 if condition B is met and ignore target 1

Comment: Regarding the the flag issue .. its just like a filter

Comment: Add 2 windowed counts to your `SELECT` to count the number of A's and B's in your data, then you'll need to use a Multicast, to put the data into 2 flows, and then use a conditional Split to filter out the data when it doesn't have an A/B flag for that flow.